# The redirect uri included is not valid - Doorkeeper GEM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

Running rails 5, with ruby 2.4.1 have doorkeeper running as oauth provider, I have setup an application with the redirect url

```
https://367d3dcf.ngrok.io/oauth/callback
```

When I try and call:

```
https://367d3dcf.ngrok.io/oauth/authorize?client_id=d34aa96a7481c2c96826ff97e75f7a4f5d2056a08bbd0e87eeec3d7f4864d493&redirect_uri=https://367d3dcf.ngrok.io/oauth/callback&response_type=code
```

I get the response "The redirect uri included is not valid." I can see that the redirect urls match and I also did the following in rails console:

```
uri = 'https://367d3dcf.ngrok.io/oauth/callback'
Doorkeeper::OAuth::Helpers::URIChecker.matches? uri, Doorkeeper::Application.find_by_uid(uid).redirect_uri
# => true
```

If I set the redirect URL to `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`, it works, but I don't want to do it in testing mode.

Also found that it works if I go through the web console of doorkeeper `oauth/applications`

Any ideas why its not valid?